# How to call method of instance of generic type when it's type argument is unknown?

Tags: c#, generics

This seems like basic problem, but I'm struggling with it (maybe because of tiredness).

E.g. - if i create instance of repository like this =>

```
var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
// repository type==object :(
var repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(repositoryType);
```

What's the best way to call `repository.All()` method? Is reflection the only way?

Comment: Are you also asking how to do using reflection?

Comment: Nope. Reflection ain't hard for such a task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether `Repository<>` exposes some non-generic interface (like [`ITable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.aspx) compared to [`Table<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) in LINQ-to-SQL). If not, you have to use reflection. If it *does*, then cast to the non-generic interface:

```
IRepository repository = (IRepository)ServiceLocator
    .Current.GetInstance(repositoryType); 
IList data = repository.All();
```

In 4.0, you could also consider `dynamic`:

```
dynamic repository = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(repositoryType); 
IList data = repository.All();
```

Comment: Created `NonGenericRepository` that takes entityType as an argument in constructor. Seems awkward but better than reflection.

Comment: I'd have gone with an interface myself, but whatever works. And indeed, reflection and generics are not good friends.

Comment: Wondering - if type covariance in .Net 4.0 could solve this (I haven't checked it thoroughly yet)?

Comment: Not unless you a: have an interface, b: can define it as strictly "in" or "out", c: have a common reference-type ancestor, etc. In short: I don't think it is a likely option.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 3.5, it is not possible to do this without reflection or worse.

Comment: Building a method at runtime using System.Linq.Expressions would be worse.

Comment: The only real competition to Expression is ILGenerator... for me Expression wins every time ;-p

Comment: Ouch... Now my head aches. Seems that it's time for a break.